# Get average CPU utilization on Windows

Tags: windows

I need the average CPU utilization from the past 15 minutes. I need the value from the command line or in PowerShell.

Does Windows keep a rolling average of CPU utilization from for example the past 15 minutes? (basically similar to when you type "uptime" on Linux and get the rolling average of CPU load from the past 1, 5, and 15 minutes). If not, what other options are there to get this value, or is there a completely different approach I should be taking to monitoring whether my server has been under heavy stress in average in the past 15 minutes?

---

(I do know of a very inefficient way to do this: log to disk, and then read the log and calculate the average manually. Roughly something like this (PowerShell):

```
# Initialize a perf counter
logman.exe create counter DashboardCpuTime -c "\processor(_total)\% processor time" -a --cnf --v -f bincirc -max 1 -o "c:\perflogs\DashboardCpuTime.blg" -si 00:00:10
logman.exe start DashboardCpuTime


# Get the average value by stopping, reading the log, calculating the average in PowerShell, and starting again
logman.exe stop DashboardCpuTime
(Import-Counter -Path "c:\perflogs\DashboardCpuTime.blg" -Counter @("\processor(_total)\% processor time") | ForEach-Object { $_.CounterSamples.CookedValue } | Measure-Object -Average).Average
logman.exe start DashboardCpuTime
```

but I am not satisfied with the overhead and complexity of this, and the fact that the samples taken every 10 seconds are still instantaneous values, and not 10 second averages)

Comment: Check out PowerShell's [Get-Counter](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee872428.aspx).

Comment: Get-Counter cannot give values from the past.

Comment: It looks like Windows is not keeping past CPU usage -- it would seem a basic function to ask to the OS, but apparently it's not... I found no performance counter that looks like the "load average" of UNIX systems